# E/CameraSource: Failed to open camera -> Camera "0" disabled by policy

Tags: android, android-camera

Currently my app has an issue with camera access. On Android 10 it works fine but issue happening on Android 11.

```
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISABLED (1): connectHelper:1747: Camera "0" disabled by policy
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1022)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:550)
```

When freshly install app from Android studio to the device and approve the permissions it works for awhile but at some time later it starts showing up the error. So it will present the preview view without camera due the error.

Current use case is that broacast receiver will notify the service and that presents the camera preview for user.

Here's the app manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.software">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.app.myservice" />
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
        <receiver
            android:name=".service.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".service.MyAppNotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.software.CAM_PREVIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".service.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="camera" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I checked that there are no work policies set up and for Android background restrictions
I added the manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"`

And that doesn't work.
What it requires that I can use the flag START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND?

Is there any workaround that this can be done without bringing up the application foreground? The camera preview works in such case if the app is visible in foreground but that makes bad user experience.
Thanks,
-MD-

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services (your app cannot use the camera from a foreground service launched from the background on Android 11+)

Comment: Thanks I have seen that as well. That's why I thought that START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND would work with adding right policies vendor related but wasn't sure what all it requires. Posted answer how I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up solution that

1. Bring the activity up in on in broadcast receiver - onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) call.
2. startPreview
3. moveTaskToBack(true) in main activty onResume call.

And it seems to be working fine.